# Change the value of image src in javascript problem

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys I'm pretty new to JavaScript.
I want to change the picture dynamically:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="full-with">
    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'. $product->productImg) }}" class="attachment-shop_single wp-post-image" alt="" title="" id="myImg">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="summary entry-summary col-md-6">
  <h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">
    {{$product->productName}}
  </h1>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <form class="cart" method="post" action="{{ route('cart.add') }}">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="product_size" class="grey">Model</label>
        <span class="red">*</span>
        <select class="form-control" id="productModel" name="product" onchange="myFunction();">
          <option value="">Wybierz model produktu...</option>
          @foreach($productModels as $productModel)
          <option value="{{$productModel->id}}">{{$productModel->modelName}} - {{$productModel->modelPrice}} @if($productModel->modelPriceCurrency === 1) PLN @else EUR @endif</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleSelect1">Ilość:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="quantity">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div itemprop="description">
          <p>{!! nl2br(e($productCategory->categoryDescription)) !!}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Dodaj do wyceny..">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JS

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {

        var model = [
        <?php foreach($productModels as $productModel):?>
          <?=$productModel?>,
        <?endforeach;?>
        ];

        var e = document.getElementById("productModel");
        var selectedModelId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value - 1;

        var modelImg = model[selectedModelId].modelImg;

        document.getElementById("myImg").src = 'storage/' + modelImg;
    }

    myFunction();   
</script>
```

The problem is that when I'm changing the source of the picture javascript adds "/item" between: http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/storage/C1pNsNdD6XeJie4RBOp8RjyDocPvcNFGdJJUGfiU.jpeg

Link should look like:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/C1pNsNdD6XeJie4RBOp8RjyDocPvcNFGdJJUGfiU.jpeg

Is there any option to delete "/item"?

Comment: Don't add pictures this way, use image icon in editor (these links are broken anyway - 127.0.0.1 is localhost, so we cannot access your pictures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete `/item`, do this:

```
var modelImg = model[selectedModelId].modelImg;
var source = '/storage' + modelImg;
source = source.split("/item");
source.join("");
document.getElementById("myImg").src = source;
```

Comment: This answers misses the actual error which is a lacking slash at the start of the path. It "fixes" the problem by adding the slash and then adding a lot of nonsense since "/item" will never occur within the actual string.

Comment: Code-only answers aren't particularly helpful. You should explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is simple, you are setting the src attribute to a relative path. `storage/` will create a link relative to your current url, so I'm gussing your url is "http://localstorage:8000/storage/something.php" when you get this error.

To make this path absolute from the site root instead you simply prepend it with another slash. That way it will always be relative to your site root no matter what the current url is.

```
document.getElementById("myImg").src = '/storage/' + modelImg;
```

The solution by Jack Bashford also adds this slash before the url but then does a lot of nonsense by splitting the string on something that doesn't exist and then joining an array with only one item.